# Parent/child one-to-many distinguish Null vs. zero children

Tags: python, database, database-design, sqlalchemy

I have a parent child relationship as follows.  I'd like to be able to distinguish between null children (e.g. information not known yet) vs. zero children.  This is the approach I'm currently taking.  It works, but seems a bit cumbersome.  Is there a better way to go about this?

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, ForeignKey, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship


Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///')


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    children = relationship('Child', uselist=False)


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'), primary_key=True)

    child_items = relationship('ChildItem')

class ChildItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'childitems'

    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('child.id'), primary_key=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
p = Parent()
assert(p.children is None)  # Would like to be able to do something like this.

c = Child()
c.child_items.append(ChildItem())
p.children = c

assert(p.children is not None)
```

Comment: Only when first creating instances? What if you retrieve an instance from the database, do you need to know if it has ever had children set?

Comment: Yes, I want to know if it has ever had children set.

Comment: If `Parent.chlidren` returned `None` when called, then you wouldn't be able to `.append()` to the collection in the first instance. Using a `Boolean` field (to store the state of set/not set) and a `hybrid_property` / `setter` its pretty simple to make the collection return `None` if never set, but an action like this `p.children.append(Child())` wouldn't work as you cannot append to a `NoneType`. So you'd have to ensure the first time you set the attribute you used `p.children = [Child()]` syntax. I can post the code if you want but not sure if that's what you are after.